# Matlab - printing in a directory

Tags: matlab, directory, figure

I am trying to print an eps file 'flow.eps' in folder 'figures'. This script is in folder 'auto'.

```
path1   = fullfile('Documents', 'MATLAB', 'auto', 'figures', 'flow.eps');
print(gcf, '-depsc', 'path1')
```

However, I am getting 'path1.eps' in 'auto'. It is working when written like this:

```
print(gcf, '-depsc', '~/Documents/Matlab/auto/figures/flow.eps')
```

I am trying the former one because I want my script to be compatible with both windows & unix.

Comment: I missed a sentence during copy-paste. Yes, I want the former script to work perfectly. Any hint will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do the first method is:

```
path1   = fullfile('Documents', 'MATLAB', 'auto', 'figures', 'flow.eps');
print(gcf, '-depsc', path1)
```

**path1, <---> 'path1'**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get the following error: Cannot create output file 'Documents/MATLAB/auto/figures/flow.eps'

Error in print (line 210)
    pj = name( pj );

Comment: Did you check the case sensitivity of MATLAB and Matlab?

Comment: yes, it is MATLAB & the full path is: /Users/raj/Documents/MATLAB/auto for the script file in Mac.

Comment: use the whole string then! Have you tried? or use `fullfile(matlabroot,...`

Comment: I tried the full string, it gives the same previous error. And, the later option with 'matlabroot' is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot for that answer, I tried many of them, but seems no one is correct.

Some suggested to change the directory to the specified path you want to save your picture, others suggested `movefile` command but they are time consuming.

The solution is simply, if you wanna print in any folder, the `print` command uses the file name as a complete path otherwise it is saved in current directory.

So I wanna save the figure to F:\Folder\Subfolder\filename , I just type

```
print(gcf,'F:\Folder\Subfolder\filename', '-depsc' )
```

Or

```
print('F:\Folder\Subfolder\filename', '-depsc' )
```